# Can I find paragraphs with only anchors as children using xpath?

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to find paragraphs with only anchors (and optional whitespace) as children using XPath? I can get as far as "//p[a and not(*[not(self::a)] or text())]", which works beautifully if there isn’t any whitespace between the paragraph and anchor tags.

To give some concrete examples, I want a query which will match these (currently only matches the first one):

```
    <p><a>link</a></p>
    <p> <a>link with leading spaces</a></p>
    <p><a>link with trailing spaces</a> </p>
    <p> <a>link with leading and trailing spaces</a> </p>
```

But which does not match these:

```
    <p>Intro text <a>link</a> outro text.</p>
    <p><a>link</a> outro text.</p>
    <p>Intro text <a>link</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the following a bit nicer than @wst's solution and it also works with XPath 1.0:

```
//p[a and not(*[not(self::a)] or text()[normalize-space()])]
```

Comment: So far I'm liking this one for its simplicity!

Answer (score 1):

Close. Use `normalize-space`:

```
//p[a and not(*[not(self::a)] or normalize-space(string-join(text(),"")))]
```

`string-join` is used to get around the fact that normalize-space only accepts a single string as input.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

You are looking for all `<p>` elements that contain an `<a>` element and of which their normalized-text equals the normalized text of the `<a>` child element:

```
//p[a and normalize-space(.) = normalize-space(a)]
```

For your example it will return the following results ([Demo](http://eval.in/12575)):

```
0: <p><a>link</a></p>
1: <p> <a>link with leading spaces</a></p>
2: <p><a>link with trailing spaces</a> </p>
3: <p> <a>link with leading and trailing spaces</a> </p>
```

With your specific example data it's even possible to spare the second `normalize-space` function:

```
//p[a and normalize-space(.) = a]
```

however that might be too fragile for what you're looking for. This is Xpath 1.0 compatible.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but it will also match paragraphs with empty elements other than `<a>`. See this [fork of your demo](http://eval.in/12633).